# Getting "NA" when I run a standard deviation

Tags: r, statistics, na, stdev

Quick question. I read my csv file into the variable `data`. It has a column label `var`, which has numerical values.

When I run the command

```
sd(data$var)
```

I get

```
[1] NA
```

instead of my standard deviation.

Could you please help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try `sd(data$var, na.rm=TRUE)` and then any NAs in the column var will be ignored. Will also pay to check out your data to make sure the NA's should be NA's and there haven't been read in errors, commands like `head(data)`, `tail(data)`, and `str(data)` should help with that.

Comment: I added `str()` to your answer as I find it helpful for these sorts of debugging tasks, but didn't feel it warranted it's own answer. Hope you don't mind, feel free to roll back.

Comment: `summary(data)` is probably the easiest way to see if there are `NA` in the data.

Comment: Sometimes, as 'is.numeric()' may help.

Answer (score 12):

I've made the mistake a time or two of reusing variable names in **dplyr** strings which has caused issues.

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(gear) %>%
  mutate(ave = mean(hp)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(med = median(ave),
            ave = mean(ave), # should've named this variable something different
            sd = sd(ave)) # this is the sd of my newly created variable "ave", not the original one.
```

Comment: My problem was I named my variable "mean" which seemed like a good idea at the time! I was wondering why na.rm=T wasn't working.

Answer (score 6):

You probably have missing values in `var`, or the column is not numeric, or there's only one row.

Try removing missing values which will help for the first case:

```
sd(dat$var, na.rm = TRUE)
```

If that doesn't work, check that

```
class(dat$var)
```

is "numeric" (the second case) and that

```
nrow(dat)
```

is greater than 1 (the third case).

Finally, `data` is a function in R so best to use a different name, which I've done here.

Answer (score 0):

There may be `Inf` or `-Inf` as values in the data.

Try

```
is.finite(data)
```

or

```
min(data, na.rm = TRUE)
max(data, na.rm = TRUE)
```

to check if that is indeed the case.